# OBSOLETE - Code::Trends - a visualization of the StackOverflow dataset

Tags: app, obsolete

### About

[Code::Trends](http://code-trends.appspot.com/mainpage) is an interactive analysis of a dataset taken from StackOverflow, including:

- visualization of the technologies trends by time and location
- recommendation for similar technologies
- recommendation for developers with similar background and interests

### Examples

[How did HTML5/Flash/Silverlight usage change over time?](http://code-trends.appspot.com/timetrend?tags=html5,flash,silverlight)
[image: Time trends]

[Where are the PHP questions asked?](http://code-trends.appspot.com/loctrend?tags=php)
[image: Location trends]

[Who are the users with most answers about Android? And the most related technologies?](http://code-trends.appspot.com/recommendations?tags=android)
[image: Recommendations]

### License

The work is licensed under [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/)

### Contact

The website was developed by Andrea Cuttone. You can get in touch using andreacuttone at gmail.com

### Code

- Python for acquiring and parsing the data
- Google App Engine and Django for the web part
- Google charts, d3 and tipsy for the fancy stuff

Comment: Marvelous work, I really like it.